# Vector Tile Points on top of Polygons can't be clicked on

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have made my own vector tile .pbf data, consisting of polygons, lines and points.

The source of .pbf data are from a grouplayer of shapefiles in Geoserver, where each shapefile has been ordered so that points are at the top:

[image: geoserver layer order]

Using OpenLayers, I've styled the vector tiles and followed the example for "[Vector Tile Info](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-info.html)". The difference is mine is toggled by single click.

The problem is that I can't click on any point, even as a sprite image, if it is completely within a polygon.
It's possible to click on lines that are completely within a polygon.
Underlying polygons are selected as feature[0] when attempting to select a point.

[image: Points Rendered Under Polygons]

What might be the cause of this render order? That a point is only a single pixel?
What might be the remedy?
I'm very new to JavaScript and OpenLayers so I'm hoping it's something naive.
I need to be able to prioritize the points when they're surrounded by a polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of feature returned by `map.getFeaturesAtPixel()` seems to be random and not related to render order.  Either check all the features returned, not just entry `[0]`, or sort the array so Points/MultiPoints are lower in the sort order than LineStrings/MultiLineStrings with Polygons last

```
function rank(feature) {
  var type = feature.getType();
  if (type.indexOf('Point') > -1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (type.indexOf('LineString') > -1) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    return 3;
  }
}

map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel).sort(function(a, b) {
  return rank(a) - rank(b);
});
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I've been scratching up on Javascript and managed to get this to work, thanks for giving me something to learn.
As for the seemingly random return of feature, I suspect that the order of features returned is based on proximity to the pixel clicked (within hitTolerance). I haven't tried it without a hitTolerance but in general it makes it very difficult to click on a point without one.